# How do I see the output of data sent by JQuery to php?

Tags: php, jquery

I have this JQuery piece of code. I want to see wht php outputs. How do I print that.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
$.ajax({
     url: "script.php",
     type: "POST",
     data: { name : "John Doe" },
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(msg){
     alert(msg);
     }
});
</script>
<HTML>
```

script.php

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo $name;
?>
```

Comment: Get rid of the `dataType: 'json'` (it's not what you want in this specific case) and it should work

Comment: thanX a Lot Pekka, it workd :) & thanX to all people who answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
```

If what you are asking is how you run the PHP script, you'll have to install a web server (e.g. Apache) with the PHP extension.

Answer (score 1):

Use Firefox with Firebug and you can see exactly what you've posted and a response (if there is one) from the PHP script

Answer (score 0):

If you ask for JSON format, malformed return string is rejected. For development purposes, ask jQuery to use that of text. If you want to check the JavaScript object itself, you can dump() it in JavaSscript.

Reference source: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON
>   and returns a JavaScript object. In
>   jQuery 1.4 the JSON data is parsed in
>   a strict manner; any malformed JSON is
>   rejected and a parse error is thrown.
>   (See json.org for more information on
>   proper JSON formatting.)

Answer (score 0):

Get [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). It's a free proxy that allows you to see what's sent both ways. I suggest and recommend these add-ons too: [JSON Viewer](http://jsonviewer.codeplex.com/) and [FirePHP Inspector](https://code.google.com/p/fiddler-firephp-inspector/), the latter obviously with FirePHP.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Chrome, you can see the data that is being outputted by going to developer tools -> network -> XHR.

You can open the developer tools by right clicking on the page and clicking on inspect element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var_dump($_POST); die;
```